# create and display hexadecimal string in c++

Tags: c++, qt

I've been reading many suggestions on the same topic, and tried to implement many of them, but it seems that none of them is actually working in my environment.
I'm using QT 5, but I think the problem is not related to QT but to how the hexadecimal character 0x00 is interpreted by the language.
What I have to achieve is to display a stream of unsigned char as hexadecimal values, eg:

> Input bytes: 0x00 0x4E 0x01 0x00 0x17 0x00
>
> Display as: 0x00:0x4E:0x01:0x00:0x17:0x00

it seems quite easy, but all I get is an empty string...

The functions I wrote:

```
QString getBufferAsHexStr(const unsigned char* buf, int buffsize) {
std::string finalstring("");
char tempbuff[5];
int n=0, index=0;
for (int c = 0; c < buffsize; c++) {
    if(c == buffsize-1) {
        n=sprintf(tempbuff, "0x%02X", buf[c]);
    } else {
        n=sprintf(tempbuff, "0x%02X:", buf[c]);
    }
    finalstring.append(tempbuff, n);
    index += n;
}
QString resultStr(finalstring.c_str());
return resultStr;
}

QString getBufferAsHexStr(const unsigned char* buf, int buffsize) {
std::stringstream ss;
for (int c = 0; c < buffsize; c++) {
    if(c == buffsize-1) {
        ss << std::hex << std::showbase << buf[c];
    } else {
        ss << std::hex << std::showbase << buf[c] << ":";
    }
}
const std::string finalstring = ss.str();
QString resultStr(finalstring.c_str());
return resultStr;
}
```

Comment: FIrst, why did you make `tempbuff` in your first example have a size equal to what you *think* it should be?  You're walking a tightrope by making this size `5`.  Why not make it 10 and be safe?  As a matter of fact, it is a buffer overrun, since you're trying to stuff 6 characters into it.

Comment: @drescherjm:  Out of curiosity, why QString and not `std::string`?

Comment: That is a second option.

Comment: Using a properly sized buffer and replacing QString with `std::string`, [this code](http://ideone.com/1ypybe) shows no issue.  Also, your original code with a buffer of 5 crashes the program created with Visual Studio with a corruption error (debug build).

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the quick reply. I set tempbuff as a 5 slot array because the string it has to contain must be either 0xXX or 0xXX:, so it's 4 or 5 characters. I agree that there is a buffer overrun, I just don't get why... does sprintf add a newline at the end of the string?

Comment: @Bruno `0x%02X:`  You have 5 visible characters ("0x" + 2 hex characters + 1 colon) == 5)  plus the terminating `\0`, making this 6 characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why you started to use C++ functions with C++ types when you have a much better alternative which is `QString`. Using `QString` you might implement it as follows:

```
QString getBufferAsHexStr(const unsigned char* buf, int buffsize) {
    QString result;
    for(int i = 0; i < buffsize; ++i)
        result += "0x" + QString("%1:").arg(buf[i], 2, 16, QChar('0')).toUpper();
    result.chop(1);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Hi ixSci, your solution works pretty fine, it just doesn't show the leading 0 when it's the case, but I can work around it. To answer your question: I don't know QT that much, I am still learning to use it properly :)

Comment: @Bruno, updated the answer. Now it handles the case with 0. Also, if the answer helps you, please click on the tick mark near the answer.

Comment: thank you very much, this is a simple matter but helped me a lot. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Another version using a `QByteArray` and a joined `QStringList`:

```
QString getBufferAsHexStr(QByteArray buf) {
   QStringList byteStrings;
   for (int i = 0; i < buf.size(); ++i)
      byteStrings += QString("0x") + QString("%1").arg(buf[i], 2, 16, QChar('0')).toUpper();
   return byteStrings.join(":");
}
```

It would by called using

`QString result = getBufferAsHexStr(QByteArray(charArr, charArrSize));`